# Click [Submit] -> Hide DIV Container 1 -> Show DIV Container 2 -> Load DIVs Found in .PHP File inside DIV Container 2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Here is what I am trying to do

1 - Click Submit

2 - Hide DIV Container 1

3 - Show DIV Container 2

4 - Load All DIVs found in "PricingDisclaimer.php" into Div Container 2

---

Here is my DIV Code

```
<div id="MainContainer">

<div class="Container1">
Lalala content
<input type="submit" value="Select" id="Load_Container2"/>
</div>

<div id="Container2" style="display:none;">I want to load all of the DIVs found inside "PricingDisclaimer.php" and place them inside this container</div>
</div>
```

Here is my Javascript / Jquery Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
$("#Load_Container2").on("click", function() {
    $(".Container1").hide();
    $("#Container2").show();
    $("#Container2").load( "http://www.prismasites.com/wp-content/themes/Prismasites/PricingDisclaimer.php" );

});
</script>
```

It hides DIV Container1 [WORKS]

It shows DIV Container2 [WORKS]

PROBLEM:

It does not load PricingDisclaimer.php into #Container2

This is PricingDisclaimer.php

```
<div id="PricingBoxDisclaimer">
<div id="PBDisclaimerTLCorner"></div><div id="PBDisclaimerTMBorder"></div><div id="PBDisclaimerTRCorner"></div>
<div id="PBDisclaimerMLBorder"></div><div id="PBDisclaimerContainr"><div id="PricingDisclaimerTitle"><span><b>DISCLAIMER</b></span></div><div id="PricingDisclaimerContainer"><div id="PricingDisclaimerText">
<?php query_posts('p=1272' ); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
<br /><h1>
<?php
the_title();
echo '<br>'; ?></h1><br />
<?php
echo '<p>';
the_content();
echo '</p>';
endwhile; ?>
</div></div><div id="PBDisclaimerMRBorder"></div>
<div id="PBDisclaimerBLCorner"></div><div id="PBDisclaimerBMBorder"></div><div id="PBDisclaimerBRCorner"></div>
</div>
```

^ I want ALL of that ^

Inside here

v v v v v v

```
<div id="Container2" style="display:none;">HERE</div>
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Why don't you just `include "PricingDisclaimer.php"` at the beginning where you want to put the divs? It will be shown only when you unhide the div.

Comment: `$("#Container2").load( "http://www.prismasites.com/wp-content/themes/Prismasites/PricingDisclaimer.php" , function(response){response.append("#Container2");});` Try this, I think it might help.

Comment: @Tareq Mahmood

Because my website is a "1 main page website" with 8 Sections.

Chrome/Firefox Browsers loads all the content within hidden divs. 

Loading all of the content in my hidden divs slows down my website when it loads.

I don't want it to load the content in hidden divs until I click the submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually because, the way you are calling load, the file is being called as an standalone file, but that has some codes which has dependencies to some wordpress functions. So, it cannot be called as you are trying to call it. If you want to load it this way, you should make it independent of wp codes.  Just try to access the url in your browser and you will get this error now :

```
DISCLAIMER

Fatal error: Call to undefined function query_posts() in /srv/disk12/1806831/www/prismasites.com/wp-content/themes/Prismasites/PricingDisclaimer.php on line 4
```

**EDIT**

I see, now your link is working after you removed the WP related codes. But I found the other problem in your JS code. You have missed closing braces `});` for `$(document).ready`. Fix it like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#Load_Container2").on("click", function() {
        $(".Container1").hide();
        $("#Container2").show();
        $("#Container2").load( "http://www.prismasites.com/wp-content/themes/Prismasites/PricingDisclaimer.php" );
    }); 
}); //You missed this closing braces
```

**Cross Origin Issue**

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource.

It's because, you are sending request from a domain to a different domain, which doesn't allow cross-origin requests. You can allow that from your file `PricingDisclaimer.php`. Just add this line at the top of your file (before doing any echo or outputting any html code) :

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Learn more about : [Cross-origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: So you mean to tell me there is absolutely no way to connect it to wordpress? 

I took out all the wordpress code and it still doesn't load the divs from the .php into the div container.

Comment: @ShenHuiZhang, I see your link is working now. But I found the problem in your JS, see my edit.

Comment: Check your console. There must be some error, if it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "console"? You mean like my webhost that hosts all my .php files?

Comment: No. Right Click > Inspect Element from your page. You will find the console area where the JS errors are shown with red marking.

Comment: Wow. I never knew that. 

The console:
 "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.prismasites.com/wp-content/themes/Prismasites/PricingDisclaimer.php. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)."

What does this mean?

Comment: @ShenHuiZhang, that means, you are sending a request to a different domain which doesn't allow cross domain request. See my update above to allow cross origin request which will fix the issue.

Comment: Oh okay. Should I paste it as is or should I put it inside <script></script> tags or <?php><?php> tags?

Comment: It should be the first line after the first `<?php` tag in the file.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help you.

```js
$("#Container2").html('<iframe src="http://www.prismasites.com/wp-content/themes/Prismasites/PricingDisclaimer.php"</iframe>');
```

Comment: It works but it shows up all messed up. Check out: www.prismasites.com and scroll down to Pricing Plan Section and click the submit button.

Comment: I am not sure about the_title();  & the_content(); functions content. Please check from where [COMPANY NAME] & [DATE] values of these variables coming form. Hope you will get a solution.